# when non static block is present in constructor code " I don't get the output process"?

Tags: java, constructor, output

```
public class Test{
    int i;
    static int j;
    public Test(){
        i+=2;
        j++;
        System.out.println(i+" \t "+j);
    }
    {
        i++;
        j--;
        System.out.println(i+" \t "+j);
    }
    public Test(int i){
        this.i=i;
        j+=5;
        System.out.println(i+" \t "+j);
    }
    {
        i+=5;
        j+=7;
    }

    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        new Test();
        new Test(15);
    }
}
```

Output

```
1  -1
8   7
1   6
15  18
```

I can understand the process to take out the first two line of output  but i don't know how/process to get the output next

Comment: How can you understand the first two lines but not the other two? They behave exactly identical. The only "special" thing is that j is static, i is not and you overwrite the value of i in the second constructor but that is unrelated to the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

you get this output because of the **initializer blocks** that you have added.

**initializer blocks** are those blocks, you have two of them in your code, that will be executed **before the constructor** , when you create an object, of that class.
and also remember that in the process of creating an object of a class you call only one constructor of that class meaning that this called constructor will be executed and **the other constructors won't**.
moreover, you have set the variable j as **static, meaning that its value will remain constant and won't be reset**, or reinitialized, for all the instances of the class that will be created.

so with that all being said let's look at your code :

1. in `main()` method you first create an instance of class test via its `public Test()` constructor (I mean the first one).by doing this because you have written two initializer blocks, those initializer blocks will get executed in order from top to bottom and then constructor `public Test()` gets executed. the first initializer block changes the value of i to 1 and j to -1 and prints them. the second one adds 5 to the current value of i making it 6 and adds 7 to the current value of j, which is -1, making it 6. then the constructor gets executed and adds 2 to i making it 8 and 1 to j making it 7 and then prints them.
2. the second instance that you created does a similar thing but with the difference that this time the value of j is 7 from the previous operations, due to the static keyword behind it, but for i it is 0 again because it is not static and gets reset for every instance. again first the two initializer blocks get executed and then the constructor `public Test(int i)`.note that doesn't matter what happens to the value of i in those initializer blocks, the constructor will change the value of i to 15.

Hope it helped.